# Savitzky-Golay filtering giving incorrect derivative in 1D

Tags: python, scipy, filtering, signal-processing, smoothing

I have an x and y dataset, with x as the independent variable and y as the dependent variable.

> y=2x

I add some noise to 'y' and apply the scipy Savitzky Golay filter. When I attempt to get the first derivative of y, I get the derivative as zero.
I understand this is because of the filter takes only 'y' as the input. I would want to have a filter that considers both x and y, and also provide me with a derivative value.

Here I show my implementation with the plots indicating incorrect data.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create some sample twoD data
x = np.linspace(-3,3,100)
y = 2*x
y = y + np.random.normal(0, 0.2, y.shape)

# filter it
Zn = signal.savgol_filter(y, window_length=29, polyorder=4, deriv=0)
Zf = signal.savgol_filter(y, window_length=29, polyorder=4, deriv=1)
# do some plotting
plt.plot(x,y, label = 'Input')
plt.plot(x,Zn, label= 'Savitzky-Golay filtered')
plt.plot(x,Zf, label= 'Savitzky-Golay filtered - 1st derivative')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Result:[image]

The derivative result:
dy/dx = 2. 

I need the Savitzky-Golay filter to provide me this result. Please help me with a python implementation that considers two variables.

Comment: You can [fit a line into your results](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) and get the slope.

Comment: This is just a demonstration. I need the Savitzky-Golay filter for an algorithm dealing with a noisy signals. Those signals are too complex to be modelled with a polynomial fit.

Comment: Then please include a more realistic example. You can only get what you ask for.

Comment: The example provided by @Ankit Bansal is good because you can immediately read the value of the expected derivative (i.e. 2) and see if the implementation really gives you that number. He provided a valid "minimal example": +1 for his question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit: *Correction made for English language usage*.**

In the given case, the derivative of `y` with respect to `x` is not `dy/dx = 2`, but rather `dy/1.0 = 0.12` because `y` is defined as `y = 2x = np.linspace(-3,3,100)`.

The variable `dx` was not defined as `delta`, and the default value `delta=1.0` was used instead.

So, using `delta` which is equal to `dx` indeed resolves the issue.

```
dx = x[0] - x[1]
Zf = signal.savgol_filter(y, window_length=29, polyorder=4, deriv=1, delta=dx)
```

Answer (score 9):

To use `deriv` > 0 in [`savgol_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html), you must also give the spacing of the x coordinates.  The fix is simple: add `delta=x[1] - x[0]` after `deriv=1` in the call:

```
Zf = signal.savgol_filter(y, window_length=29, polyorder=4, deriv=1, delta=x[1] - x[0])
```